# Python Plotly, how to remove background horizontal line?

Tags: python, formatting, plotly

How to get rid of the background horizontal lines on this chart? The lines that represent the scales 5, 10, 15, etc. You can find the code below:

[image]

```
# Plotting waterfall chart for Years of Experience lost on DA Team

x_data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
y_data = [13, 23.5, 17.5, 10, 2.5] # y_data for positioning the annotations
text = ['27', '7', '5', '10', '5']

# Base
Base = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=[0, 20, 15, 5, 0], marker=dict(color='rgba(1,1,1,     0.0)',))
# Total
Total = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=[27, 0, 0, 0, 0],     marker=dict(color='#003A6F',line=dict(color='k',width=1,)))
# Individuals
Individuals = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=[0, 7, 5, 10, 0], marker=dict( color='#FFE512',line=dict(color='k',width=1,)))
# Years of Experience Left
Years_left = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=[0, 0, 0, 0, 5],  marker=dict(color='00AB39',line=dict(color='k',width=1,)))

# Put all traces in one "data" list
data = [Base, Total, Individuals, Years_left]

# Layout takes care of things like chart title, x and y axis titles and font     sizes, etc.
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Chart One',
    barmode='stack',
    yaxis=dict(title='Number of Years', titlefont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size)
                              , tickfont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size)),
    xaxis=dict(title='Names', titlefont=dict(size=xaxis_font_size)
                              , tickfont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size)) ,   
    showlegend=False
)

annotations = []
annotations_colors = ['rgba(245, 246, 249, 1)', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'rgba(245,     246, 249, 1)'] # assign colors to annotations
for i in range(0, 5):
    annotations.append(dict(x=x_data[i], y=y_data[i], text=text[i],     font=dict(family='Arial', size=14, color=annotations_colors[i]),     showarrow=False,))
    layout['annotations'] = annotations

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout) # Standard plotly way to assign     data and layout
iplot(fig, filename='Chart One')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Enlightening examples can be found at https://plot.ly/python/axes/

Simply add `showgrid=False` to your `yaxis` and `xaxis` dictionaries.

All the dict options for your xaxis can be found at https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis (and the yaxis is similarly at https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I am looking for! Accepted!

Answer (score 7):

we can update layout using `fig.update_layout()` method
by setting `showgrid = False` for both `xaxis` and `yaxis` parameters.

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
              yaxis=dict(showgrid=False)
)
```

or

we can directly use `fig.update_xaxes()` and `fig.update_yaxes()` methods and assign `showgrid=False`.

```
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30847509)