# python-plotly-multiple y-axis: How to turn off grid on both subplots?

Tags: plotly-python

I am new to python and am enjoying the debugging help that stack overflow community provides.

In the following code I am able to remove y-axis grid for top subplot but unable to remove grid from the bottom subplot (row=2).

What am I doing wrong?  I appreciate your help. -VB

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig1 = make_subplots(rows=2,
                specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}],
                       [{"secondary_y": True}]])

x1_shorter = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

y1_shorter = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

y2_shorter = [202, 98, 202, 98, 202]

x1_longer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

y1_longer = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

y2_longer = [202, 98, 202, 98, 202, 98, 202, 98, 202]

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=x1_shorter, y=y1_shorter, name="yaxis data"),
    row=1, col=1, secondary_y=False)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=x1_shorter, y=y2_shorter, name="yaxis2 data"),
    row=1, col=1, secondary_y=True)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=x1_longer, y=y1_longer, name="yaxis5 data"),
    row=2, col=1, secondary_y=False)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=x1_longer, y=y2_longer, name="yaxis6 data"),
    row=2, col=1, secondary_y=True)

fig1['layout']['yaxis1']['showgrid'] = False

fig1['layout']['yaxis2']['showgrid'] = False

fig1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535950/18460516

You can remove the horizontal gridlines using update_yaxes():

```
fig1.update_yaxes(secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
fig1.update_yaxes(secondary_y=True, showgrid=False)
```

[plot w/o horizontal grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEy2h.png)